# Get_the_terms - display all post types

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

**The question has been updated. See below for latest version**

I am having troubles to see all post types when using custom posts. This is based on isotope, and the user is supposed to click on the links to see posts within that category.

All posts created by Wordpress standard posts appears, but none created with Types (Custom posts).

```
<ul id="filters" class="whitetext whitelink myeluft">
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected">Alle</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' data-filter='.foto'>Foto</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' data-filter='.video'>Video</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' data-filter='.web'>Web</a></li>
</ul>

<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=50' ); //Check the WP_Query docs to see how you can limit which posts to display ?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div id="isotope-list">
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 


        // Query posts - post_types
        $anypost = get_posts( array(
             'post_type'      => 'any' // every post type, but not attachments
        ) );

        $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "category", $anypost);  //Get the terms for this particular item
        $termsString = ""; //initialize the string that will contain the terms
            foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) { // for each term 
                $termsString .= $term->slug.' '; //create a string that has all the slugs 
            }
        ?> 
        <div class="<?php echo $termsString; ?> item col-md-3"> <?php // 'item' is used as an identifier (see Setp 5, line 6) ?>
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                          the_post_thumbnail();
                    } ?>
        </div> <!-- end item -->
        <?php endwhile;  ?>
    </div> <!-- end isotope-list -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

As you see, I have tried fixing it by inserting the following code, but it still doesn't show all post types.

```
// Query posts - post_types
$anypost = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'      => 'any' // every post type, but not attachments
) );

$termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "category", $anypost);  //Get the terms for this particular item
```

I have read [this article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms), but I found my self more loss than started/

What would be a working solution?

**Update**

By using the following code I am able to see all posts, but not being able to filter them out. See page here: http://goo.gl/e3cLuM (scroll down till you see all the posts)

```
<?php $post_type = 'any';
$post_taxonomy = 'any';
// Get all
$terms = get_terms( $post_taxonomy );

$portfolio = new WP_Query('post_type='.$post_type.'&post_per_page=-1'); ?>
// First we loop our porfolio_category to show all categories as filter.
<ul id="filters" class="whitetext whitelink myeluft">
    <a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected"><li class="smoothtrans">Alle</li></a>
    <a href='#' data-filter='.foto'><li class="smoothtrans">Foto</li></a>
    <a href='#' data-filter='.video'><li class="smoothtrans">Video</li></a>
    <a href='#' data-filter='.web'><li class="smoothtrans">Web</li></a>
</ul>

<?php if ( $portfolio->have_posts() ) : ?>
                <div id="isotope-list">
                    <?php while ( $portfolio->have_posts() ) : $portfolio->the_post();
// Get current post terms.
                        $item_terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), $post_taxonomy, $args );
                        $classes = '';
                        // Append classes to use with each item.
                        foreach($item_terms as $item_term ){
                            $classes .= $item_term->slug.' ';
                        }
                        ?>
                        <div class="<?php echo $termsString; ?> item col-md-4"> 
                            <ul class="grid cs-style-3">
                                <li>
                                    <figure>
                                        <?php // 'item' is used as an identifier (see Setp 5, line 6) ?>
                                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                                              the_post_thumbnail();
                                        } ?>
                                        <figcaption class="lefttext">
                                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                            <span class="offgrey">Nettside</span>
                                            <a href="#" class="smoothtrans">Se prosjekt</a>
                                        </figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                </li>
                            </ul>             
                        </div> <!-- end item -->
                    <?php endwhile;  ?>
                </div> <!-- end isotope-list -->
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: are you using custom taxonomy for your custom post type ?

Comment: Thanks for answering. That's a negative, but it would be a possibility to add taxonomy if it's necessary to make it work.

Comment: Have you tried array('posts_per_page'=>50,'post_type'=>any) for the WP_Query

Comment: I believe there is a syntax error somewhere in that code. At least it didn't work.

Comment: Exactly on which template is this

Comment: I'm sorry. What do you mean by which template?

Comment: Which template/page is this code on. `category.php`, `page.php`, `taxonomy.php`??

Comment: This code is on a separate PHP which is currently included on one page (index), but is going to be included on several pages.

Comment: Ok, but when a users selects a category/term, where does it lead to, which template. Or are you reloading the same page

Comment: It's reloading the same site, based on the isotope: [link]http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: @Pieter Goosen I have updated the question. Please see the original question if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has been solved.

I finally used the following code:

```
<ul id="filters" class="whitetext whitelink myeluft">
         <a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected"><li class="smoothtrans">Alle</li></a>
         <a href='#' data-filter='.foto'><li class="smoothtrans">Foto</li></a>
         <a href='#' data-filter='.video'><li class="smoothtrans">Video</li></a>
         <a href='#' data-filter='.web'><li class="smoothtrans">Web</li></a>
</ul>

<?php
$terms = get_terms( $post_taxonomy );

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'any',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'post_taxonomy' => 'any',
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args); 


// Loop post_type
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div id="isotope-list">
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 

        $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "category");  //Get the terms for this particular item
        $termsString = ""; //initialize the string that will contain the terms
            foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) { // for each term 
                $termsString .= $term->slug.' '; //create a string that has all the slugs 
            }
        ?> 
        <div class="<?php echo $termsString; ?> item col-md-4"> 
            <ul class="grid cs-style-3">
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <?php // 'item' is used as an identifier (see Setp 5, line 6) ?>
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                              the_post_thumbnail();
                        } ?>
                        <figcaption class="lefttext">
                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                            <span class="offgrey"><?php echo(types_render_field( "produkt", array( 'raw' => true) )); ?> / <?php echo(types_render_field( "produsert", array( 'raw' => true) )); ?></span>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" class="smoothtrans">Se prosjekt</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
            </ul>             
        </div> <!-- end item -->
        <?php endwhile;  ?>
    </div> <!-- end isotope-list -->
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/toucheffects.js"></script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

There wasn't that many changes I had to do, but there were a few.

Thanks for everyone who commented and came with working ideas.

Note that there are some bugs in the code I haven't fixed up yet.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming we have custom post type called `portfolio` and custom taxonomy called `portfolio_category`

```
<?php $post_type = 'portfolio';
$post_taxonomy = 'portfolio_category';
//First get all terms of portfolio_category.
$terms = get_terms( $post_taxonomy );

$portfolio = new WP_Query('post_type='.$post_type.'&post_per_page=-1'); ?>
// First we loop our porfolio_category to show all categories as filter.
<ul id="filters" class="whitetext whitelink myeluft">
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected">All</a></li>
    <?php foreach($terms as $term) : ?>
         <li><a href='#' data-filter='.<?php echo $term->slug ?>'><?php echo $term->name ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

<?php if ( $portfolio->have_posts() ) : ?>
                <div id="isotope-list">
                    <?php while ( $portfolio->have_posts() ) : $portfolio->the_post();
// Get current post terms.
                        $item_terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), $post_taxonomy, $args );
                        $classes = '';
                        // Append classes to use with each item.
                        foreach($item_terms as $item_term ){
                            $classes .= $item_term->slug.' ';
                        }
                        ?>
                        <div class="<?php echo $classes; ?> item col-md-3">
                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                the_post_thumbnail();
                            } ?>
                        </div> <!-- end item -->
                    <?php endwhile;  ?>
                </div> <!-- end isotope-list -->
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe we are into something here. I addded post_taxonomy to the posts within custom post: Foto, and it showed up. I used foto_category as taxonomy. But however, the list within the foreach which is going to display names does not work correctly. The page is to be found here: http://goo.gl/jytG7o (Scroll down till you see Siste prosjekt).

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. I meant I used foto-category as slug, and foto as taxonomy.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please see the original question if you like.

Answer (score 0):

The `any` argument is for `post_status` , I don't think it is accepted for `post_type`  (`'post_status'      => 'any'`)
(actually, it wasn't correctly implemented in some versions)

You can give *post_type* an array with some types instead:

```
'post_type' => array('post','page','event')
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I have tested it, but it didn't seem to work. I also tried to replace the arrays with custom post slugs, but that didn't work either...

Comment: then check the database and see what makes these posts different (category, etc).

Comment: I have updated the question. Please see the original question if you like.